# Localizable.strings - Why do I need to put the placeholder in the key?

Tags: objective-c, localization

In Localizable.strings file, why is it necessary to put placeholders in the key.

Assuming you use a dot notation like;

`"welcome-back.label" = "welcome back, %@"`

I've seen examples where they mix placeholders and dot notation something like this;

`"welcome-back %@.label" = "welcome back, %@"`

*^ The above might be incorrect.*

But what I don't understand is why you even need the placeholder at all in the `key` when its just a pointer to a `value`.

Can someone shed light on this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLocalizedString will replace the string on the left hand side with the string on the right hand side. The string on the right hand side must obviously be the correct string for the situation, the string on the left hand side can be anything you want. You could use keys "1", "2", "3" etc and it would work (although you would go mad).

You can improve your life as a developer with the right strategies. I tend to never use plain english text as the key, because the same English word can have many different translations (for example "key" in German can be Taste, Schlüssel, Tonart and lots of other things). Instead I write some text that describes what the text is used for.

And to avoid problems when you type in the key incorrectly, which the compiler has no chance to find, I tend to use #define statements for the keys. Much easier to keep just a list of #defines and your localizable.strings in sync, and the compiler will tell you if you misspell a #defined constant.

And I tend to use the word "format" for strings that are format strings and not used directly. So I might have in one header file

```
#define kWelcomeBackLabelTitleFormat @"WelcomeBackLabelTitleFormat"
```

and in the localizable.strings file

```
"WelcomeBackLabelTitleFormat" = "welcome back, %@";
```

(The #define saves you if you used "WelcomebackLabelTitleFormat" by mistake with a lowercase b).

Comment: I wasn't sure if the placeholder on the left was due to a validation reason or because in a different language the placeholder might be elsewhere.  But you're help has resolved  it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it in the key, it's there to make life easier for people who read the code in the future so they can easily tell that a parameter should be passed, what it's for and therefore which variable should be used. If you want to use some other specification to indicate this that's fine. If you want to make it super terse and hard to use that's also fine, just discouraged...